# Moving a rect with translate and a time delay?

Tags: processing

I have  this code. It was ment to print a rect 10 times moving it 60 pics to the right every time with a delay of 1000 ms before each print. It doesn't, and I don't understand why. Could someone please explain it to me?

```
int time;
int wait =1000;

void setup()
{
  time = millis();
  size(800, 200);
  background(255);
}

void draw() {
int i=0;
  while (i<10){
    if(millis() - time >= wait){
      time = millis();
    }

  translate(60, 0);
  rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are preventing the draw() function from finishing. You do this by setting an integer i = 0 and then you say while (i<10) {}. Meanwhile you never change i thus the code is doing an infinite loop inside the while(), and never reaches the end of the draw() function which will refresh the canvas with the rectangles you want. You can't set your own rendering loop because Processing requires its own to finish in order to display. Thus you have to "go with its flow" and define everything along its loop, the draw() function.. Sort of like this:

```
int time;
int wait =1000;
int translateX;
void setup()
{
  time = millis();
  size(800, 200);
  background(255);
}

void draw() {
  if (millis() - time >= wait) {
    time = millis();
    translateX +=60;
    translate(translateX, 0);
    rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Petros mentioned you got yourself into infinite loop but it is easier to use `delay()` function and condition only how much times was rec printed.

```
int wait = 1000;
int translate = 0;
int count = 0;

void setup()
{  
  size(800, 200);
  background(255);
}

void draw() {
  if(count < 10)
  {
    delay(wait);
    translate += 60;
    translate(translate, 0);
    rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    count++;
  }  
}
```

**EDIT**

Upgraded version so you can change `MAX`of printed rec. And it will also change size of canvas according to number of rec. Also added data stream to right and shifting down as wanted in comment.

```
int wait = 100;
int translate = 0;
int count = 0;
static final int MAX = 10;

void setup()
{  
  size(60*MAX, 12*MAX);
  background(255);
}

void draw() {
  if(count < MAX)
  {
    delay(wait);
    translate(translate, count*11);
    translate += 60;
    rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    fill(50);
    text("Data", 15, 10);
    noFill();
    count++;
  }  
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm, Thanks, but it doesn't do what I expected it to. If I change the count value in the if statement to 20 it'll exceed the window. If I then exchange the 0 in the translate statement with the count variable I would expect to see the last rect keep moving 1 down after each draw. When it doesn't, is it then because I'm not moving the window but only the grid? And how could it be done? Later on the recht should be a data stream and I need to see the last entry in the window. Sorry for not specifying this need.

Comment: Updated!
You should also edit you question if you expect something else.